# How do I start an xml activity from a dialog?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-activity, adt

I'm trying to load an XML activity I have when a user clicks the link button below.

Can someone assist? I have NO idea how to do so (and it's driving me nuts!)

All I want to do is when a user clicks "Link" have them sent over to AppActivity2.java/main2.xml

```
package com.mkyong.android;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class AppActivity extends Activity {

final Context context = this;
private Button button;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    // add button listener
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            context);

        // set title
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Settings Menu");

        // set dialog message
        alertDialogBuilder
            .setMessage("Link or Delete?")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Link",new     DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                    // if this button is clicked, close
                    // current activity
                    AppActivity.this.finish();
                }
              })
            .setNegativeButton("Delete",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                    // if this button is clicked, just close
                    // the dialog box and do nothing
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

            // create alert dialog
            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

            // show it
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: are you aware of intent? It takes you from one page to another.

Comment: please refer to android intents and how to fire them on button click, you should do research before you post your question

Comment: I'm not but I just read up on it a bit via http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

However I'm still not sure the line of code I can add to this to switch to another page.

Comment: There is no such thing as "an XML activity".  I think some Android tutorials are needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom);
        dialog.setTitle("Title...");

        // set the custom dialog components - text, image and button
        TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text);
        text.setText("Android custom dialog example!");
        ImageView image = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.image);
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonOK);
        // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
        dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                   Intent it = new Intent(AppActivity.this, urActivity.class);
                    startActivity(it);
                     dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        dialog.show();
```

Also check below link for more detail.

http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/

Comment: This is the page I used to build the project - but now I need to know how to move to another page (perhaps using intent?) when a user clicks "Link" in the code above.

Comment: Awesome! I got it... the only thing is now I'm getting a 
Cannot instantiate the type Intent error - any suggestions?

Comment: Ahhhhh! I tried to run the code via emulator after deleting the errors and resaving and confirming they didn't come back and the entire application force closes using the script above. :(

Comment: not able to understand u so now what ur problem or error u facing now ??

Answer (score 0):

You have to use an intent to open the desired activity. The code will look like this:

```
//create the intent (must be final in order to be able to acces it from the inner class)
final Intent nextActivityIntent = new Intent(this, AppActivity2.class);
alertDialogBuilder
        .setMessage("Link or Delete?")
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setPositiveButton("Link",new     DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                // if this button is clicked, close
                // current activity
                AppActivity.this.finish();
                //start the activity using the intent
                startActivity(intent);
            }
          })
```

Answer (score 0):

In your setPositiveButton method block, write a code to start activity

```
        .setPositiveButton("Link",new     DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                //start new activity

                Intent intentAppActivity2 = new Intent(AppActivity.this, AppActivity2.class);
                startActivity(intentAppActivity2);

                // if this button is clicked, close
                // current activity
                AppActivity.this.finish();
            }
          })
```